# Is it possible to search logs in DataDog for a term appearing anywhere in the log message?

Tags: logging, datadog

We haven't been very disciplined about structuring our logs across different components (because we were using Loki/Grafana, where it doesn't really matter, and only recently switched to Data Dog, and now it is biting us).

Suppose, I have a piece of data (let's say, a `user_id=12345`), that could appear anywhere within a json log message.
For example, it could be

```
{
   "content": "Deleted a user id 12345"
}
```

Or it could be

```
{
   "content": "Failed to create a user"
   "attributes": {
      "exception": "Duplicate key 12345"
   }
}
```

Or

```
{
   "content": "Sending email to the user"
   "attributes": {
     "mdc": {
        "user_id": "12345"
     }
   }
}
```

Or

```
{
   "content": "Generated user report"
   "thread": "user-report-generator-12345"
}
```

So, in grafana, I was able to just search for `|= "user" |= "12345"`, and it would work for all those possibilities (possibly, also some "false positives", but that's fine) ...

But in datadog, if I just do `12345` it only matches `content` ... And if I do `@mdc.user_id:12345`, it only finds messages where user id appears in the MDC. Etc.

So, the question is if there is anyway to search for a term, that can appear *anywhere* within the row log message? Or do I have to name all possible attributes explicitly?

Comment: Seems like we can't search inside json logs at all for some reason. Seems more of a bug than a feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for search_string, try:

```
search_string OR "*search_string*" OR @search_string:*
```

That's the best solution I found.